# How to make the `import` statement work properly inside the code created using the node:vm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodevm

In our project we have the custom `console` object which is used as a logger.
So we need to replace the default `console`.
For this purpose we decided to use the **vm** module.
But we are facing the problem while using **imports** inside the code created with `vm.Script`:

**application.js**:

```
import path from 'path';

console.log(path.resolve('./apps'));
```

**main.js**:

```
const context = {
  console,
  global: {},
  module: {},
  exports: {},
  require,
};
context.global = global;

const sandbox = vm.createContext(context);
const fileName = './application.js';
const src = await fsp.readFile(fileName, 'utf8');
const script = new vm.Script(`module.exports = () => {\n${src}\n};`);
const execute = script.runInNewContext(sandbox);

execute();
```

**Output:**
*Error:* *Cannot find module 'path'*

**Question**:
How to make imports work properly inside the **application.js** file?

Comment: Uh, don't use `module.exports = () => {\n${src}\n};` ? An `import` declaration is obviously invalid inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a [`new vm.Script`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#class-vmscript) if you want to create a module. Use a [`new vm.Module`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#class-vmmodule) instead! Notice that the API is still experimental though.

Comment: would you mind to help with vm.Module in new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130595/how-to-link-the-imported-dependencies-of-module-created-by-vm-sourcetextmodule-t)?

Comment: The error "TypeError: Module is not a constructor" happens when changing to vm.Module

Comment: @JefersonTenorio Looks like it's [`new vm.SourceTextModule`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#class-vmsourcetextmodule) now and the `Module` class is abstract. Well, the API is marked as experimental still…