# How to link the imported dependencies of module created by vm.SourceTextModule to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-vm2

Let's say we are creating a module called `app` by constructing a new `vm.SourceTextModule` object:

```js
const context = {
  exports: {},
  console,  // custom console object
};
const sandbox = vm.createContext(context);

const app = new vm.SourceTextModule(
  `import path from 'path';
   console.log(path.resolve('./src'));`,
  {
    context: sandbox,
  }
);
```

According to the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#class-vmmodule) to obtain the default export from `path` module we should "link" the imported dependencies of `app` module to it.
To achieve this we should pass `linker` callback to `app.link` method:

```js
async function linker(specifier, referencingModule) {
    // the desired logic...
}

await app.link(linker);
```

How to implement `linker` function properly so that we could import `path` module in newly created `app` module and use it:

```js
await app.evaluate();  // => /home/user/Documents/project/src
```

P.S. We are using `TypeScript`, so I checked if we have installed types for `path` package.

**package.json**:

```json
"@types/node": "^17.0.31",
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35848 where someone posted a code snippet.

From there I've adapted the following linker callback:

```
const imports = new Map();

async function linker(specifier, referencingModule) {
  if (imports.has(specifier))
    return imports.get(specifier);
  
  const mod = await import(specifier);
  const exportNames = Object.keys(mod);
  const imported = new vm.SyntheticModule(
    exportNames,
    function () {
      exportNames.forEach(key => imported.setExport(key, mod[key]));
    },
    { identifier: specifier, context: referencingModule.context }
  );

  imports.set(specifier, imported);
  return imported;
}
```

<strike>The code snippet from the GitHub issue didn't work for me on Node 18.7.0 as is, because the evaluator callback passed to the constructor of `SyntheticModule` is somehow called with `this` set to `undefined`. This may be a Node bug.</strike>

I also cached the imported SyntheticModules in a Map because if they have internal state, creating a new SyntheticModule every time will reset that state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and attention, i really appreciate it.
This stuff is a bit tricky for my current programming level.  
I tried to run your code snippet.
The line `const mod = await import(specifier);` causes the `Error: Cannot find module 'path'` error.
But outside of the `linker` body `await import('path')` - acts as expected.
Maybe i'm missing something..

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be.

Comment: If you have some time, please check out the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335799/using-the-dynamic-import-inside-the-module-link-callback-causes-an-error) caused by the above dynamic import problem.
Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: The issue with `this` is that you changed `function(){` to `() => {`, which discards the `this` passed in by SyntheticModule for the current `this` at the place where the function is defined, which was `undefined`.

Comment: How did I miss that! I must have typed over the snippet instead of copy-pasting it, and unconsciously written an arrow function.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. import context does not belong the vm. So, you can load the modules that way but you cannot execute them. In order to solve that problem, I compiled the import as a function to the context. Instead of const mod = await import(specifier), do this: 

const importFunction = compileFunction(`return import('${specifier}')`, [], { parsingContext: referencingModule.context, importModuleDynamically: specifier => import(specifier) });
const mod = await importFunction();
Hope this helps.