# Using the dynamic import inside the `module.link()` callback causes an error

Tags: node.js

In our project we need to use the `vm.Module` (to run the source code in the custom context).
Let's say the source code is: `import path from 'path';`

According to the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#class-vmmodule) using a `vm.Module` object requires three distinct steps: creation/parsing, linking, and evaluation.
Let me try to follow the above steps:

1. Create the module called `app` by instantiating the `vm.SourceTextModule` class:

   ```
    const app = new vm.SourceTextModule(`import path from 'path';`);
   ```
2. Define the linking callback (the "linker"):

   ```
   async function linker(specifier, referencingModule) {
    console.dir({ specifier, referencingModule });  // (1)

    const mod = await import(specifier);  // (2) throws an Error
    console.dir(mod);  // (3) never executed

    const exportNames = Object.keys(mod);
    const imported = new vm.SyntheticModule(
      exportNames,
      () => {
        exportNames.forEach((key) => imported.setExport(key, mod[key]));
      },
      { identifier: specifier, context: referencingModule.context }
    );
    return imported;
    }
   ```

   Now we can "link" the imported dependencies of the `app` module to it:

   ```
    await app.link(linker);
   ```
3. And finally evaluate the Module:

   ```
    await app.evaluate();
   ```

**Results:**
Line (1) outputs the next debugging log:

```
{
  specifier: 'path',
  referencingModule: SourceTextModule {
    status: 'linking',
    identifier: 'vm:module(0)',
    context: undefined
  }
}
```

So as for now everything works as expected, now we just need to use the dynamic import to import the `path` module, **but**:

Line (2) causes an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'path'
```

Line (3) never executed.

**Question:**
What i am missing and how to make dynamic import in line (2) work?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get this working myself; currently on Node v20, the code you posted works for me perfectly.

---

**Edit:** Edited because @petrzjunior left a comment saying that this wasn't an answer, I'd like to clarify.

I sort of disagree with the comment; the question was:

> What i am missing and how to make dynamic import in line (2) work?

My answer, more succinctly could be:

> Use Node v20

or,

> Using Node v20, the provided code works properly - so what you need to do to "make dynamic import (..) work" is update to Node v20 and, "what I am missing" is likely a new enough version of Node that fully supports the code you have posted.

Which both logically and in my opinion seems like a completely valid answer to the question, both explaining 'how to make (..) work' as well as answering 'What i am missing' with what they're missing is likely a new enough version of Node to support what they're attempting to do and providing exact Node version that worked with their provided code.

Perhaps I should've been more detailed/concise or maybe left out the the first sentence containing the anecdote about myself trying to get it working but even then it still provided all the required information to answer the question, that being basically: "your code works on node v20".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34343869)

Comment: I've edited and updated my answer; I do believe it did answer the question originally (well, questions as it was technically a two-part question) asked and have also updated my answer to clarify and be more explicitly clear towards the exact asked questions, as asked.